# Sliding, variable "window" with highest density of rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm tring to retrive from a table the time slot with the highest frequency/density of records.

Let say I have a log table like this:

```
datetime   | action | username | highest_time_slot
--------------------------------------------------
2013-09-30 | update | username | 
2013-12-15 | update | username |
2014-03-01 | update | username | *
2014-03-02 | update | username | *
2014-03-03 | update | username | *
2014-03-05 | update | username | *
2015-05-20 | update | username |
```

From this table is possible to see that the user operated with a higher frequency during the time slot between 2014-03-01 and 2014-03-05.
Is there any smart tricky way to retrive this time slot?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: How does your database (or *you*) define *slot*? Does *slot* mean just any number of consecutive days?

Comment: I just mean the period (time slot, time window, from date A to date B) where there is the highest concentration of operation. - not just the number of days, but which days (from/to)..

Comment: Ok. What does *highest concentration of operation* mean? You've highlighted four rows that don't quite have consecutive dates. If the dates don't have to be consecutive, then clearly the highest concentration of operation is from 2013-09-30 to 2015-05-20.

Comment: You are going to need a person to look at the output to decide what is the 'highest activity' group given that you allow 'gaps' in the days of the group. However, a plot showing days of activity on a graph would be useful and fairly easy to implement. As would grouping by consecutive days

Comment: I'll try to give another example: let's say we have a table where we log a record any day is raining outside. At the end of the year I want to know which is the period of the year with the highest number of rainfalls. E.g. between January 15 and Feb. 20. How can I get this interval? (Let's call this interval the one with the highest concentration, density, frequency, whatever... I hope I get the idea)

Comment: I was about to answer your question then you changed it completely. The current question is unclear. You need to at least include your desired output based on the sample data and explain the results. Provide more details.

Comment: I rolled back this question to version 4, which is the version the active participants were working with. I also edited the title to make it clearer, and perhaps more attractive to SQL gurus.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: I rolled back this question to the version we were all working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets start with a table definition and some INSERT statements. This reflects your data before you changed the question.

```
create table log_test (
  datetime date not null,
  action varchar(15) not null,
  username varchar(15) not null,
  primary key (datetime, action, username)
);

insert into log_test values
('2013-09-30', 'update', 'username'),
('2013-12-15', 'update', 'username'),
('2014-03-01', 'update', 'username'),
('2014-03-02', 'update', 'username'),
('2014-03-03', 'update', 'username'),
('2014-03-05', 'update', 'username'),
('2015-05-20', 'update', 'username');
```

Now we build a table of integers. This kind of table is useful in many ways; mine has several million rows in it. (There are ways to automate the insert statements.)

```
create table integers (
  n integer not null,
  primary key n
);
insert into n values 
 (0),  (1),  (2),  (3),  (4),  (5),  (6),  (7),  (8),  (9),
(10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16), (17), (18), (19),
(20), (21), (22), (23), (24), (25), (26), (27), (28), (29),
(30), (31), (32), (33), (34), (35), (36), (37), (38), (39),
(40), (41), (42), (43), (44), (45), (46), (47), (48), (49);
```

This statement gives us the dates from log_test, along with the number of days in the "window" we want to look at. You need to `select distinct`, because there might be multiple users with the same dates.

```
select distinct datetime, t.n
from log_test
cross join (select n from integers where n between 10 and 40) t
order by datetime, t.n;
```

```
datetime     n
--
2013-09-30   10
2013-09-30   11
2013-09-30   12
...
2015-05-20   39
2015-05-20   40
```

We can use that result as a derived table, and do date arithmetic on it.

```
select datetime period_start, datetime + interval t2.n day period_end
from (
  select distinct datetime, t.n
  from log_test
  cross join (select n from integers where n between 10 and 40) t ) t2
order by period_start, period_end;
```

```
period_start  period_end
--
2013-09-30    2013-10-10
2013-09-30    2013-10-11
2013-09-30    2013-10-12
...
2015-05-20    2015-06-28
2015-05-20    2015-06-29
```

These intervals are off by one; 2013-09-30 to 2013-10-10 has 11 days. I'll leave that repair up to you.

The next version counts the number of "happenings" in each period. In your case, as the question was originally written, we just need to count the number of rows in each period.

```
select username, t3.period_start, t3.period_end, count(datetime) num_rows
from log_test
inner join (
  select datetime period_start, datetime + interval t2.n day period_end
  from (
    select distinct datetime, t.n
    from log_test
    cross join (select n from integers where n between 10 and 40) t ) t2
  order by period_start, period_end ) t3
on log_test.datetime between t3.period_start and t3.period_end
group by username, t3.period_start, t3.period_end
order by username, t3.period_start, t3.period_end;
```

```
username  period_start  period_end  num_rows
--
username  2013-09-30    2013-10-10  1
username  2013-09-30    2013-10-11  1
username  2013-09-30    2013-10-12  1
...
username  2014-03-01    2014-03-11  4
username  2014-03-01    2014-03-12  4
...
username  2015-05-20    2015-06-28  1
username  2015-05-20    2015-06-29  1
```

Finally, we can work some arithmetic magic, and get the density of each "window".

```
select username, 
       t3.period_start, t3.period_end, t3.n, 
       count(datetime) num_rows,
       count(datetime)/t3.n density
from log_test
inner join (
  select datetime period_start, t2.n, datetime + interval t2.n day period_end
  from (
    select distinct datetime, t.n
    from log_test
    cross join (select n from integers where n between 10 and 40) t ) t2
  order by period_start, period_end ) t3
on log_test.datetime between t3.period_start and t3.period_end
group by username, t3.period_start, t3.period_end, t3.n
order by username, density desc;
```

```
username  period_start  period_end  n   num_rows  density
--
username  2014-03-01    2014-03-11  10  4         0.4000
username  2014-03-01    2014-03-12  11  4         0.3636
username  2014-03-01    2014-03-13  12  4         0.3333
...
```

**Suggestions for refinement**

You might want to change the date arithmetic. As it stands, these queries simply add 'n' days to the dates in the test table. But that means the periods won't be symmetric around gaps. For example, the date 2014-03-01 appears after a long gap. As it stands now, we don't try to evaluate the density of a "window" that *ends* on 2014-03-01 (a "window" that comes at the first value in a gap from before it). This might be worth thinking through for your application.

Comment: I'm terrible sorry I've changed my question! I was just trying to figure out a different example to make my question more clear, even thought the current scenario is the one I'm working on. Sorry for that...

Comment: your answer is amazing! It's exactly what I was looking for. The basic idea is to create any possible time interval and calculate its num_rows and density. Very very tricky! Thank you very much

Comment: @Mauro: There was a bug in it. You need `select distinct` (or its equivalent) in the innermost subquery. Multiple users might have activity on the same date, but you want unique (distinct) combinations of date and interval. I've made the correction throughout, I think.